# Website ERR_CONNECTION_RESET - Client not sending SSL hello packet to server

Tags: apache, ssl, tcp, centos, centos7

I have a website on Centos 7.4 running Apache 2.4.6

A user reported that they could not access the site on their mobile device (as of the last few days). I was able to recreate this issue on an Android Pixel. When I use a mobile 4G network, I immediately get an ERR_CONNECTION_RESET page if I try to go to any page of the website. When I use my home WIFI network on the phone, with the same browser, I can view all pages as expected.

I tested this, with the same results, on both Chrome and the native browser on this device.

I have enabled SSL logging in apache (ssl_engine, ssl_access and ssl_error) and none of these logs (nor the general httpd error log) show anything relating to this issue. I guess the connection doesn't reach apache?

There is nothing relating to this in the firewalld log either (though I'm not sure it would be logging such things?).

I have greped the fail2ban log too for the mobile network IP and found nothing.

I have also used Wireshark/Tshark to analyse the packets. Comparing the output when I access the site using WIFI (where it connects as expected) and when I use the mobile 4G network (where it fails to connect).

```
  2 0.000065217 [Server IP] -> [Client IP] TCP 74 https > 63878 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=28960 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=244522926 TSecr=140533229 WS=128
  3 0.003907594 [Client IP] -> [Server IP] TCP 74 63879 > https [SYN] Seq=0 Win=65535 Len=0 MSS=1326 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=140533229 TSecr=0 WS=256
  4 0.003951717 [Server IP] -> [Client IP] TCP 74 https > 63879 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=28960 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=244522930 TSecr=140533229 WS=128
  5 0.154191732 [Client IP] -> [Server IP] TCP 66 63879 > https [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=87808 Len=0 TSval=140533290 TSecr=244522930
  6 0.165703034 [Client IP] -> [Server IP] TCP 66 63878 > https [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=87808 Len=0 TSval=140533290 TSecr=244522926
  7 0.187358660 [Client IP] -> [Server IP] TCP 56 63879 > https [RST, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=8222720 Len=0
  8 0.204245316 [Client IP] -> [Server IP] TCP 56 63878 > https [RST, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=8222720 Len=0
```

This is as far as the connecting goes on the mobile network. We never get to the next stage which is "SSL 571 Client Hello" on WIFI (the client sending the server a hello).

Any ideas on what could be causing this, or ways I can debug this issue further?

Answer (score 0):

So I've finally got to the bottom of this error, after a few days of scratching my head and spending a lot of time researching and fiddling with the server config.

It turns out the website has been blocked by a couple of ISPs who have decided to now deem the website as containing adult content (it's doesn't and has never had this issue before in its 10 year history).

Rather than providing any kind of useful redirect to let a user know why they can't access the site, they simply don't send a hello packet and up comes the ERR_CONNECTION_RESET.

I must say, this is something that had crossed my mind early on in my investigations. However, rather unhelpfully, when logging into my mobile phone account it said the adult content filter was off. I discovered this wasn't in fact the case when I called them to double check!

If you think this could be happening to you, here's some quick checks:

- If all other websites seem to be working fine, try to visit an adult website and see if you also get an ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
- Then check with your ISP to see if it's blocking adult content.